# What is a definition of data-efficient machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

I found some papers referring to a particular machine learning algorithm as 'data efficient.' I understand the definition at an intuitive level (say, an algorithm with a good ratio of generated insights over inputs). But I suspect there is a more formal definition, which I would like to know.

Comment: It's mostly a buzz word; I wouldn't put too much credence in a firm definition because of the Sorites paradox.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think you can certainly come up with useful definitions if you consider specific algorithmic classes. However, I agree with you that it may be hard to generalize.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I think in statistical learning theory there exist bounds for _sample efficiency_ that guarantee certain error rates for certain sample sizes (big-O style).